# How to Access Java Objects through Javascript in Safari

Tags: java, javascript, safari

i have written an Java Applet, which is loaded in HTML and its function is called through javascript.

The Applet ist loaded with this html-Code:

```
<applet id="xapplet" code="xapplet" archive="java/xApplet.jar" height="0" width="0"></applet>
```

In the applet is a function, which returns an ArrayList.

```
public ArrayList<String> GetXY()
{
    ArrayList<String> lStrX=new ArrayList<String>();

        lStrX.add("X");
        lStrX.add("Y");

    return lStrX;
}
```

THe function is called through javascript:

```
var applet = document.getElementById('xapplet');
var xy = applet.GetXY();
```

In most browsers I can access the Properties of the java-Object, which is given as result. I have successfully tested this with Firefox, Internet Explorer and Chrome.
Only in Safari the Objects I get have the type "CRuntimeObject", which don´t have any property or function.

So it seems to me, that in Safari i have to do something different. Can anyone can help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know how to do it on Saphari but I'd recommend you to make some changes to your java code. Your method should return array, not list. I believe that in this case you will be able to access the element of this array from java script in all browsers.

Comment: Also an array is presented as a "CRuntimeObject". So i have tried just to return a string. That worked. Now I have found the following: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0183.html I will try return the array in Json-coding as String. Thanks.